# Is there a css equivalent to 'align="center"'?

Tags: html, css

I tried:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

But it doesn't center the elements in my table cells. I have a combination of text and `<span>` elements in the `<td>`s.

Once I set 'align="center"' in any of the `<td>` elements, it does center.

How do I achieve this in the stylesheet?

Btw, when I do `text-align: center` that works for text. But not for other elements like `<span>`s.

Edit:

The span has the following class, if that affects the alignment issue:

```
.dot {
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #333;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Note: `margin: 0 auto;` does the same thing in less lines of code

Comment: Thanks @drachenstern. Always looking for ways to reduce unnecessary code :)

Comment: @drachenstern: No, it doesn't - proof: http://jsfiddle.net/pzRPA/11/ and http://jsfiddle.net/pzRPA/10/

Comment: Crozin....that looks like the exact same thing to me.

Comment: @Crozin ~~ Ummm, you made a mistake in your code: you are testing `margin: 0 auto;` against `margin: 0 auto 10px auto;` ... idk why tho. Check your code again, and check your inheritance.

Comment: @marcamillion ~ if you don't see the 10px bottom margin on all those elements, you might want to go check it again. I promise his code (which is a valid proof of why `margin: 0 auto;` doesn't always do what you want) shows two different elements.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`margin:0 auto;` will work on

- block level non-floated, static/relative positioned elements with an **explicit width set**
- intrinsic width elements like images/objects/tables

`text-align:center` will work on

- inline/inline-blocks

For your situation you can probably do..

```
#container { text-align:center; }
#container span.block-level-spans { margin: 0 auto; }
```

**or** make the spans inside `inline-block` instead of `block`.

EDIT:

> Inline-block: This value causes an element to
>   generate a block box, which itself is
>   flowed as a single inline box, similar
>   to a replaced element. The inside of
>   an inline-block is formatted as a
>   block box, and the element itself is
>   formatted as an inline replaced
>   element.

Comment: Wonderful....making the span 'inline-block' and adding that span-block-level-spans selector seemed to have done the trick. Amazing! Can you provide a link as to what 'block-level-spans' does and why it works? Thanks.

Comment: It's worth noting that `margin: 0 auto` doesn't work on IE unless you force it into (so-called) standards compliant mode by using a `DOCTYPE`, which is something you should be doing anyway.

Comment: An inline-block is basically an inline element allowed to receive a width/height. It's much like a float except you don't have to worry about it clearing. It can be given a vertical align. Sometimes you have to specify `top` if it doesn't align properly to the top.

Comment: The selector I typed out was just some random selector. You probably don't need it.

Answer (score -3):

I did a quick search on google and found this:

span is an inline element and therefore can't be aligned. Make it a p or a
 div instead of a span, or explicitly make the span block-level by using
 display:block.

Found at:  [Velocity Reviews Forumn Link](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t161668-how-to-center-a-span-element-using-external-css.html)

Comment: Further down in that post there is more info, specifically:  text-align centers the text within the span. As the span is only as
 wide as the text it contains, centering that text has no effect.
 
To center the span you need to apply text-align: center; to whatever
 block level element is the span's parent.

Comment: REVIEW of low quality posts: No! Referenced discussion is from 2005. CSS allows you to alter element's appearance completely nowadays.